# How does Angular2+ handle auth guards?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I wonder how the Angular's authorization check flow looks like. Let's say I have following authentication guards (classes implementing the `CanActivate` interface):

- asynchronous `isLoggedGuard` returning `Observable`;
- asynchronous `isNotBannedGuard` returning `Promise`;
- synchronous `isUncompletedGuard` (returning a `boolean`)

and a route defined like:

```
  {
    path: 'some-path',
    component: SomePathComponent,
    canActivate: [isLoggedGuard, isNotBannedGuard, isUncompletedGuard]
  }
```

1. How will it be handled? Will all guards be invoked at once and just one time?
2. Is there any good way to make it's sequential so `isUncompletedGuard` guard will be checked after
   `isLoggedGuard` gives true?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460661/angular-2-guards-waiting/44462275#44462275)