# How to wait for guards in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

If i specify three guards on a route, it seems as though all guards are evaluated immediately.

`{path: '', component: OptionsComponent, canActivate: [ GuardOne, GuardTwo, GuardThree]}`

The problem I have is I don't want `GuardTwo` to run until GuardOne has finished. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589878/multiple-canactivate-guards-all-run-when-first-fails ?

Comment: @maddockst I was wondering on what forced you into needing to load your guard synchronously? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Z.Bagley I'm using children routes and wanted to use a guard for all of those children.

Comment: @maddockst, did my answer help?

Comment: @Maximus haven't had chance to use it yet, will update once I do

Comment: @maddockstm got it, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute Multiple Asynchronous Route Guards in Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641092/execute-multiple-asynchronous-route-guards-in-order)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think that's possible in the 4.1.3. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/router/src/router.ts#L921) is the code that runs the guards:

```
  private runCanActivate(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const canActivate = future._routeConfig ? future._routeConfig.canActivate : null;
    if (!canActivate || canActivate.length === 0) return of (true);
    const obs = map.call(from(canActivate), (c: any) => {
      const guard = this.getToken(c, future);
      let observable: Observable<boolean>;
      if (guard.canActivate) {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard.canActivate(future, this.future));
      } else {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard(future, this.future));
      }
      return first.call(observable);
    });
    return andObservables(obs);
  }
```

This simplified piece:

```
// array of all guards
canActivate.map((guard)=>{
     observable = guard.canActivate()
})
```

runs all guards in a sequence without waiting for the previous to finish.

One possible solution would be to have one service that implements `CanActivate` and combines other guards:

```
class Combined {
  constructor(private gA: GuardA, private gB: GuardB) {}

  canActivate(r, s) {
        return gA.canActivate(r, s).then(()=>{ return gB.canActivate() });
  }
}

... 
{path: '', component: OptionsComponent, canActivate: [ Combined ]}
```

Comment: So would it be possible to build them synchronously in a separately service, then map in that service that synchronously builds them?

Comment: Solid answer, but do you know when this type of situation is needed?

Comment: what do you mean? since you asked the question you probably have such situation :)

Comment: I didn't ask, I was working through an answer for OP when your answer came up and was just curious :)

Comment: @Z.Bagley, ah, I see, sorry. Let's ask the OP :)

Comment: @Z.Bagley, In my case , I have a common guard to fetch/validate the token and other guards to check authorization in specific modules only . Is this a valid situation to use these ?

Comment: @Sachin Yep yep, this more or less just creates the promise definitions in one file to chain in (rather than building parts of promise chains inside individual guards). Pretty elegant tbh for making clean `canActivate` definitions